# How can I check a List collection for an object that has a particular property?

Tags: c#, generics, search, collections

I have a `List<IAgStkObject>`. Each `IAgStkObject` has a property called `InstanceName`. How can I search through my List to find if any of the contained IAgStkObject(s) have a particular InstanceName? In the past I would have used a foreach loop.. but this seems too slow.

WulfgarPro

Comment: No, that's still the only way to do it. LINQ can hide the loop from you, but it can't eliminate it altogether. Alternatives include a keyed collection, but I assume there's some reason why you're using a `List<T>` in the first place.

Comment: @Cody Gray - It's a `BindingList<T>` .. but all the same.

Comment: Even more reason you're stuck with the collection type you have. I'm pretty sure you can't bind to a dictionary (but I've been wrong before).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the only thing you have is a List (not ordered by InstanceName), there is no faster way (if you do similar tests often, you can preprocess the data and create e.g. a Dictionary indexed by the InstanceName).

The only way different from “the past” would be those useful extension methods allowing you to write just

```
return myList.Any(item => item.InstanceName == "Searched name");
```

Answer (score 2):

If the list is sorted by the InstanceName, you can use binary search algorithm, otherwise: no.

You would have to use some more advanced data structure (like the sorted list or dictionary). I think dictionary would be the solution for this. It is very fast and easy to use.

But think: **how many of the objects do you have**? Are you *sure* looping through them is performance issue? If you have < 1000 of  the objects, you absolutely don't have to worry (unless you want to do something in real time).

Comment: @Wulfgar: Still, for a reasonably-sized collection, you shouldn't have any performance issues. Have you actually tried it and determined that it's too slow? You could also consider spinning off a second thread to handle this, that way the UI will be updated in real-time if *possible*, but it won't slow down other operations if the user is busy doing something else. (Like the real-time spelling checker in Microsoft Word.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
list.Any(o => o.InstanceName == "something")
```

But you cannot avoid looping through the list (in the Linq case it's done implicitly). If you want a performance gain, change your data structure. Maybe a dictionary (InstanceName -> `IAgStkObject`) is appropriate?